# Two different gradients in one html button

Tags: html, css, gradient, linear-gradients

What I am trying to do is I want to keep the top 50% of the html button to have a gradient say from #FFF to #BBB and the bottom 50% should remain in one color lets say #111. I can't figure out a way to do it, any help would be largely appreciated.

The code of my button is:

```
<button class="Button1" type="submit">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4094444/is-it-possible-to-have-2-different-background-colors-for-a-button-well-css-butt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The css:

```
.Button1 {
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #fff 0%, #bbb 50%, #111 50%);
}
```

This should do the trick in latest browsers. It's up to you to make it cross-browser compatible. (I personally like the Photoshop-esque interface of http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sample from Bootstrap that should help you out with button gradients. This also covers most modern browsers.

```
.btn-info {
color: #ffffff;
text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
background-color: #49afcd;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top,#5bc0de,#2f96b4);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,0 0,0 100%,from(#5bc0de),to(#2f96b4));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,#5bc0de,#2f96b4);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top,#5bc0de,#2f96b4);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,#5bc0de,#2f96b4);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
border-color: #2f96b4 #2f96b4 #1f6377;
border-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.1) rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ff5bc0de',endColorstr='#ff2f96b4',GradientType=0);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled=false);
}
```

Hope that helps.(these are sort of teal, so you'll have to change that part)